# Buttons have to display at bottom in TabBar

Tags: android, tabs

- I done a four tabs located at bottom of the screen.Then I created a
  five buttons that was displayed in top of the screen.
- Now my problem is that five buttons have to display in the bottom of
  the screen.But above the tab bars.
- Below I am posted the codes for that:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="5" >

              <TableLayout 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TableRow
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="BOOKS" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="LIBRARY" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MATH" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"                        
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MUSEUM" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="+24" />
                    </TableRow>
                 </TableLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Anybody can help me with these.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `TableLayout` Outside of `FrameLayout`...

Try Code Something Like This...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="5" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="BOOKS" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="LIBRARY" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MATH" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MUSEUM" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="+24" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your LinearLayout to RelativeLayout
2. Set your TabWidget android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" Set an id to your
3. FrameLayout and set android:layout_above="@+id/your_tab_widget_id"

Answer (score 0):

> try this.....

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
             <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   ..............................
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```